# How to edit nmap output

Tags: nmap

I need to count how many devices has port 80 open with nmap. I tried with "nmap -p80 --open 192.168.153.*" but this does not print what i want.

I want the following output:
"Number of devices with port 80 open: 2"

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Would you be willing to create a shell script that runs and grabs the output from the nmap command and `echo` output in the style you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to use a shell script;

```
nmap 192.168.1.* -p80 --open  | grep report > output;printf "Number of devices with port 80 open: ";  cat output| wc -l
```

Output:

```
Number of devices with port 80 open: 3
```